# How to get data from Excel spreadsheets using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I'm trying to find a way to extract data from an Excel spreadsheet using any methods with javascript or jquery to place onto my html page. I've googled various things finding that certain methods only work on IE and others are out-dated, but I can't find any definitive examples that I can use to apply to the simple "find cell based on choices in from row and column." If someone could point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative. I need this to work cross-browser as well.

Comment: Is it google sheet spreadsheet or an excel file?

Comment: great tutorial: http://www.techchattr.com/how-to-read-excel-files-with-php

Comment: It's an excel file and I only need to extract the data from the file via javascript and jquery. PHP isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will convert an xlsx file to JSON. Once it's in JSON, it is trivial to manipulate.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script>
var ExcelToJSON = function() {

  this.parseExcel = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
      });

      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
        // Here is your object
        var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
        console.log(json_object);

      })

    };

    reader.onerror = function(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  };
};
</script>
```

For very large excel files that might lock up or crash the browser look into HTML5 [Webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: I can't get this to work. It comes up undefined on ExcelToJSON. Also, the file isn't that large luckily so there will be no locking up or crashing.